# cannot find the syntax to insert the value from the textfield to mysql database through java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using JOptionPanes to get the values from the textfields and use those values to insert into a table but i cant seems to find a good example or similar problem on the web.i am using eclipse ide and mysql for a database. please help, thanks, 
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.sql.*;

public class MainMenu extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    private DefaultTableModel model; 
    private JLabel mainMenulbl;
    private JButton quitBtn;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton bookDelete;
    private JButton bookAdd;
    private JButton bookSearch;
    private JButton printLibraryCustomers;
    private JButton printBranchInfoButton;
    private JButton printListOfBooks;
    private JTable table;
    private Connection conn;
    Object[][] data;
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    String[] columnNames;

    public MainMenu() {

        data = new Object[rows][columns];
        columnNames = new String[columns];

        table = new JTable();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainMenulbl = new JLabel("Library Database Functions", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mainMenulbl.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        bookAdd = new JButton("(1)-  Add A Book");
        bookDelete = new JButton("(2)-  Remove Book");
        bookSearch = new JButton("(3)- Search A Book");
        printBranchInfoButton = new JButton("(4) Print branch information");
        printLibraryCustomers = new JButton("(5)-  Print List of Customers");
        printListOfBooks = new JButton("(6)- Print List of Books");

        quitBtn = new JButton("(7)-  Quit");
    }

    public void init() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarydb", "root", "at0m1cma55");

        } catch (Exception connectException) {
              connectException.printStackTrace();
            }

        setSize(400,400);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));

        mainPanel.add(mainMenulbl);

        mainPanel.add(bookAdd);
        mainPanel.add(bookDelete);
        mainPanel.add(bookSearch);
        mainPanel.add(printBranchInfoButton);
        mainPanel.add(printLibraryCustomers);
        mainPanel.add(printListOfBooks);
        mainPanel.add(quitBtn);
        add(mainPanel);

        //adding action listener to quit buttons
        bookAdd.addActionListener(this);

        bookSearch.addActionListener(this);
        printListOfBooks.addActionListener(this);
        printLibraryCustomers.addActionListener(this);
        printBranchInfoButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitBtn.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int BOOK_ID; String title;
        String publisher_name;
        String query; 
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        if (e.getSource() == bookAdd) {

        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydb";
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "at0m1cma55");
          PreparedStatement pstmt;
            //getTxt1 stuff
        JTextField text1 = new JTextField(15);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this),
            text1, "Enter BOOK_ID", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            String getTxt1 = text1.getText();
            pstmt.setString(BOOK_ID, getTxt1);

            //getTxt2
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField(15);
            //int okCxl = 
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this),
            text2, "Enter title", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);

        String getTxt2 = text2.getText();
        pstmt.setString(title, getTxt2);

            //getTxt3
        JTextField text3 = new JTextField(15);
            //int okCxl = 
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this),
            text3, "Enter publisher_name", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            String getTxt3 = text3.getText();
            pstmt.setString(publisher_name, getTxt3);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOOKS (`BOOK_ID`, `title`, `publisher_name`) VALUES (`"+getTxt1+"`, `"+getTxt2+"`, `"+getTxt3+"`)");
        pstmt.executeQuery();

        }

        if (e.getSource() == bookSearch) {
            JTextField textArea = new JTextField(15);
            //int okCxl = 
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this),
            textArea, "Enter the book id to search the book", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            String text = textArea.getText();
            try {
                 String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydb";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "at0m1cma55");
                query = "select * from books where book_id="+"'BOOK_ID'"+" ";
                 // create the java statement
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                 // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                BOOK_ID = rs.getInt("BOOK_ID");
                title = rs.getString("title");
                publisher_name = rs.getString("publisher_name");
                System.out.format(" %s, %s, %s\n", BOOK_ID, title, publisher_name);
                }

                st.close();
                } catch(SQLException exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}

        }

        if (e.getSource() == printListOfBooks) {
            try {
             //String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydb";
                //Class.forName(myDriver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "at0m1cma55");
                String query = "select * from books";
              // create the java statement
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();

             // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                BOOK_ID = rs.getInt("BOOK_ID");
                title = rs.getString("title");
                publisher_name = rs.getString("publisher_name");
                System.out.format(" %s, %s, %s\n", BOOK_ID, title, publisher_name);
                }
                  st.close();
            } catch(SQLException exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}

        }
        if (e.getSource() == printLibraryCustomers) {
            try {

                //String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydb";
                //Class.forName(myDriver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "at0m1cma55");
                String query = "select * from borrowers";
              // create the java statement
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();

             // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    int card_no = rs.getInt("CARD_NO");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    String address = rs.getString("address");
                    String phone = rs.getString("phone");
                    String unpaid_dues = rs.getString("unpaid_dues");
               System.out.format(" %s,%s, %s, %s, %s\n", card_no, name, address, phone,unpaid_dues);
                }
                  st.close();
            } catch(SQLException exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}

        }
        if (e.getSource() == printBranchInfoButton) {

        try {

            //String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydb";
            //Class.forName(myDriver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "at0m1cma55");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM branches";
          // create the java statement
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

         // execute the query, and get a java resultset
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) 
            {

                int Branch_id = rs.getInt("BRANCH_ID");
                String Branch_Name = rs.getString("Branch_Name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                System.out.format(" %s, %s, %s\n", Branch_id, Branch_Name, address);
            }
              st.close();
        } catch(SQLException exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}


        }

        if (e.getSource() == quitBtn)

        { 
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an action listener on the submit button, when the submit button is pressed get the value of the text area, and process that value with an MySQL insert

Comment: did you tried your Code? do you get errors when running it? or what is your problem exactly?

Comment: yes, i think the only thing i am having problem with is the syntax to get the information from textfield assigning it to the title column in mysql for example : String getTxt2 = text2.getText(); pstmt.setString(title, getTxt2); //but this syntax is wrong for assigning the texfield value to a column in mysql database

Comment: i'll give you a sample code how you insert, select/delete using PrepairedStatements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, as per my comment, here is a sample code:

**all you need is justcteating a db table with 3 STRING fields(_ID,_NAME;_MAIL) and setting the DB-Variables(password,server,...etc) in DBM.java**

NOTE: *in order to connect to MySQL server, java needs mysql-connector-java.jar, if you don't have it in your project Build path, then download it and add it as external jar to your project Build path Libraries (right click on your project in eclipse, then select build path->configure path, then add external jars)*

DB-Connection Manager Class: DBM.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBM{
    private String db_server;
    private String db_user;
    private String db_password;
    private String db_driver;

    public Connection connection = null;

    public DBM() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    private void init()throws Exception{
        // edit these line as your env.
        db_server   = "DB-SERVER";
        db_user     = "DB-USER";
        db_password = "DB-PASSWORD";
        db_driver   = "JDBC-DRIVER";
        Class.forName(db_driver);
    }   

    public Connection initConnection() throws Exception{
        if( this.connection == null ){
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db_server, db_user, db_password);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        }else if( this.connection.isClosed() ){
            this.connection = null;
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db_server, db_user, db_password);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
        return this.connection;
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null ){
                this.connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void commitConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed() ){
                this.connection.commit();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void rollbackConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed() ){
                this.connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

User.java Class:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class User{

    private String      id;
    private String      name;
    private String      mail;

    private static String db_table = "db_user";
    public User(String id, String name, String mail) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public boolean doUpdate(boolean commit, boolean close){     
        try {           
            DBM dbm = new DBM();
            User.clientUpdate(dbm, this, close, commit);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static User getById(DBM dbm, String id, boolean close) throws Exception{
        User o                 = null;
        PreparedStatement preState = null;
        ResultSet resultSet        = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+db_table+" WHERE _ID=?";
            preState   = dbm.initConnection().prepareStatement(sql); 
            preState.setString(1, id);
            resultSet  = preState.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
            // the numbers 1 means the first column in your db tableshould be in my case here the id
           // 2 means the second col is the name ...etc, change this to me
                o = new User(resultSet.getString(1),resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getString(3));
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if( preState != null )
                preState.close();
            if( close && dbm.connection != null )
                dbm.connection.close();         
        }
        return o;
    }

    public static boolean clientUpdate(DBM dbm, User o, boolean close, boolean commit) throws Exception{        
        boolean returnValue = true;
        PreparedStatement preState = null;
        try {
            User dbo = getById(dbm,o.getId(), false);           
            if(dbo==null){
                String sql = null;
               // 1st ? is the fisrt db table col  = 1 in setString(2)
               // 2nd ? is the secone db table col = 2 ...etc


                sql = "INSERT INTO "+db_table+" VALUES(?,?,?)";
                preState = dbm.initConnection().prepareStatement(sql); 
                preState.setString(1, o.getId());
                preState.setString(2, o.getName());
                preState.setString(3, o.getMail());
                preState.executeUpdate();
            }else{              
                String sql = null;
                sql = "UPDATE  "+db_table+" set _NAME=?,_MAIL=?  WHERE _ID=?";
                preState = dbm.initConnection().prepareStatement(sql); 
                      // 1 = first ?, 2 = second ? , ...etc
                preState.setString(1, o.getName());
                preState.setString(2, o.getMail());
                preState.setString(3, o.getId());
                preState.executeUpdate();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            returnValue = false; 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if( preState != null )
                preState.close();
            if( dbm.connection != null ){
                if( commit ){
                    if( returnValue )
                        dbm.connection.commit();
                    else
                        dbm.connection.rollback();
                }
                if( close )
                    dbm.connection.close();
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getName();
    }

}
```

MyGUI.java Class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyGUI extends JFrame{  
    private JTextField idField;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField mailField;
    public MyGUI(){  

        setTitle("Settings");


        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUserid = new JLabel("User-ID");
        lblUserid.setBounds(12, 22, 100, 24);
        getContentPane().add(lblUserid);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("User-Name");
        lblUsername.setBounds(12, 50, 100, 24);
        getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblUserMail = new JLabel("User-Mail");
        lblUserMail.setBounds(12, 77, 100, 24);
        getContentPane().add(lblUserMail);



        idField = new JTextField();
        idField.setBounds(114, 22, 124, 24);
        getContentPane().add(idField);
        idField.setColumns(10);

        nameField = new JTextField();
        nameField.setColumns(10);
        nameField.setBounds(114, 50, 124, 24);
        getContentPane().add(nameField);

        mailField = new JTextField();
        mailField.setColumns(10);
        mailField.setBounds(114, 77, 124, 24);
        getContentPane().add(mailField);



        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setBounds(114, 105, 124, 25);
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveData();
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnSave);
        setBounds(10, 10, 270,270);

        setResizable(false);



        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        setVisible(true);
    }  


    protected void saveData(){
        String id = this.idField.getText();
        String name = this.nameField.getText();
        String mail = this.mailField.getText();
        // you have to validate these inputs before inserting to data base      
        User user = new User(id, name, mail);
        boolean result = user.doUpdate(true, true);
        if( result ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Saved successfully");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"DB Failure...");
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String [] params){
        new MyGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You have already initialized connection object in init(), then why again in actionperformed() method?

2.setter method syntax is setString(int, String);
 where int is  parameterIndex the first parameter is 1, the second is 2.

3.Syntax of prepared statement is:

```
         PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";

           pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
          pstmt.setInt(1, valueInt);
          pstmt.setString(2, "Stringvalue");
           pstmt.setLong(3, 10000L);
           pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just figure out after looking at these sample codes and surfing more on the web, thank you